# variable enviada por $_POST no se envia

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, server-side-rendering

Hola tengo una tabla que utiliza Serverside para el llenado, en la última columna tiene 1 botón para editar el registro, al seleccionar editar se carga un modal pero quiero que me envie a otra página junto con el id del registro ya que actualmente tengo un formulario el cual recibe una variable post y se cargan los datos con php. He estado investigando y no encuentro ejemplos o soluciones, por lo tanto estoy utilizando el siguiente código de ajax el cual si me redirecciona pero no envía la variable "id" pruebo imprimiendo en consola y si muestra el id. Este es el boton que llama a la función.

```
"defaultContent": " <a href='#' class='editar' >Editar</a> </div></div>"
```

Aqui dejo el código de javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var user_id, opcion;
    tablaUsuarios = $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "serverside/serversideUsuarios.php",
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": -1,
            "defaultContent": " <a href='#' class='editar' >Editar</a> </div></div>"
        }],
    });
    
$(document).on("click", ".editar", function() {
        fila = $(this).closest("tr");
        id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "editarpaciente.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(respuesta) {
                window.location.href = 'editarpaciente.php';
            }
        });
    });
```

> Archivo editarpaciente.php

```js
<?php

$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
echo "ID: ".$id;

?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar o si tienen un tutorial que me puedan recomendar para entender mejor, de antemano gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un FormData para enviar parametros por ajax

```
$(document).on("click", ".editar", function() {
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('id', id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "editarpaciente.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            window.location.href = 'editarpaciente.php';
        }
    });
});
```

El `FormData()` permite generar un estructura parecida al tag form de html y enviarlo facilmente por ajax.
Puedes consultar la documentacion del [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de concepto, porque no es así como funcionan las peticiones AJAX.

```
$(document).on("click", ".editar", function() {
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "editarpaciente.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id },
        // El código de arriba hace que se ejecute la petición
        // enviando por POST la variable id
        success: function(respuesta) {
            // Si todo va bien, aquí recibes la respuesta
            // En lugar de analizarla, simplemente redireccionas
            // Y se "pierde" el dato que querías enviar
            // Porque esto se está enviando por GET y sin variables
            window.location.href = 'editarpaciente.php';
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que deberías hacer es recibir el formulario de `editarpaciente.php` y colocarlo en la ventana modal:

```
$(document).on("click", ".editar", function() {
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "editarpaciente.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(respuesta) {
            // respuesta es el código HTML del formulario para editar
            // se debe asignar como contenido de la ventana, en lugar de redirigir
            $('modal').html(respuesta);
        }
    });
});
```

**Notas:**

- Estoy suponiendo que tienes un elemento con `id="modal"` que es donde se debe mostrar el formulario. Si tiene otro ID, solo cámbialo.
- `editarpaciente.php` debe devolver solo el formulario, sin etiquetas `<html>`, `<head>` ni `<body>`, porque todo eso ya existe en la página actual.
- Solo falta que proceses el formulario, de preferencia, también con una petición AJAX para que no se tenga que recargar la página.
- En caso de que algo no funcione, por favor comenta esta respuesta explicando con detalle el problema y edita la pregunta para agregar código HTML del modal y el formulario para editar.